# how to use joins query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models *Client* and *Project*.

### Models

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
end
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :projects
end
```

I have the following records inside the *clients* and *projects* tables:

[image]

[image]

I want to display the an project record with the client name. What query do I need in my controller?

### Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = #your query here
  end
end
```

Comment: You tagged your question all Rails versions from 3 to 5. What version do you actually use?

Comment: If the Rails version is not relevant to the question I suggest removing all Ruby on Rails version tags.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to use a `JOIN` query. But I would suggest using [`includes`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to avoid N+1 queries.

```
# in your controller
@projects = Project.includes(:client)

# in your view (simplified – without html tags)
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= project.name %>
  <%= project.client.client_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: **Note:** Keep in mind that this code raises *"NoMethodError: undefined method \`client_name' for nil:NilClass"* if *client* can be `nil`. In this case check for the presence of *client* first, or use the [safe navigation operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver) (`&.`).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your rails versions is > 5

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @projects = Project.left_outer_joins(:client).select("projects.*, clients.name as client_name").group("projects.id")
    end
end
```

With above query you will get one another attribute in single project `client_name` which will contain project's client name. If you want to do on application level You can go with ray's answer, if you want to do on database level, you can write above query